# Page scroll to top after next step with jQuery

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, jquery

Using jQuery we are appending content in this link.
http://enfolytics.com/NaturallyWhite/booking
If we are selecting bottom service from the list, then on next screen it will automatically focus on the first record or focus to the top of the page.
Can you please help me.

Check Screenshot for better understanding. [image][image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the success part of your AJAX call for http://enfolytics.com/NaturallyWhite/photostudio/index/customerdata/?method=getCustomerData&... you'll need to add the code for scrolling to the top of the page. Or alternatively is there is any JS rendering the contents of that page you could use it that JS, it depends on your source code really.

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
```

Where `"slow"` is the animation speed, it also accepts a number in milliseconds.

It's hard for me to give a more in-depth answer without seeing your code as this isn't really related to the Magento platform.